# Execution failed for task ':amplify_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, flutter, aws-amplify

[4:11 PM] Mangukiya  Nisarg

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':amplify_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0xb5d477b) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0xb5d477b

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1